# bat file script to check if string contains other string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to write a batch file that will check if a variable contains specific value.
I tried to do the following:

```
If "%%a"=="%%a:%pattern%" (
    echo Yes
) else (
   echo No
)
```

input example:
%%a="bob binson"
%patern%="binson"

I never get Yes printed!
can anyone please tell what i missed or give an example of how (s)he would do it?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substring operations are not available in `for` replaceable parameters. You need to assign the data to a variable and then execute the operation on this variable

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    >"tempFile" (
        echo bob binson
        echo ted jones
        echo binson
    )

    set "pattern=binson"

    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("tempFile") do (
        echo data: %%a

        set "line=%%a"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        if "!line:%pattern%=!"=="!line!" (
            echo .... pattern not found
        ) else (
            echo .... pattern found
        )
        endlocal
    )

    del /q tempFile
```

Comment: Thank you too much indeed :)