# Using a pattern with IF - where is this documented?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In a recent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997011/bat-file-script-to-check-if-string-contains-other-string) I've found a solution where a pattern was with IF (see below). I have never seen this before and I could not find any documentation on this. So my question is: where can I find documentation on this

```
 if "!line:%pattern%=!"=="!line!"
```

Comment: The linked post also has a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` which enables delayed variable expansions. These are written as `!var!`. Are you asking about the syntax? Or how the linked post actually works? If the later, ask there as a comment to the answer.

Comment: that's not an `if` issue, but a variable issue. Documented in `set /?`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It's not about IF or SET but about variable replacement. This information is missing from the built-in help in windows

Comment: It's described in `set /?` under `Environment variable substitution has been enhanced as follows:`

Comment: Thanks so much. You are right. I missed the passage under the SET help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best source for documentation on CMD I know is http://ss64.com/nt/.

For your example two links are important:

http://ss64.com/nt/if.html

http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

The first one is about IF and the second explains what `!...!` means.

Comment: Thank you for the link to ss64.com. I found what I was looking for under Variable Edit/Replace